# PhpStorm project not opening when .idea file exist

Tags: phpstorm

When I try to open project it is opening but without .idea file and I can't save settings. Then I create .idea manually and project doesn't open anymore

Comment: PhpStorm is supposed to create the `.idea` folder automatically on project opening in case it doesn't exist. Are you sure your user has permission to write into the project folder?

Comment: Thanks for answer. yes permissions are normal. now .idea is creating but directories are not visible in Project folder. Can't understand what is happening

Comment: I've seen that happening when the `.idea` folder was removed while the project was still open. Please try closing the project, delete the `.idea` folder once again, and re-open the project. Any better?